# Count multiple df columns where order does not matter using pandas or other python library

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `df`.

Combat information result of Pokémon battles:

[image: Combat information result of pokemon battles]

In my code the name of the `df` is combat. I want to count all the possible fighting scenarios (combinations) for columns `combat.loc[:,'First_pokemon_type':'Second_pokemon_type']`. I have tried the following line of code `combat.groupby(by=["First_pokemon_type","Second_pokemon_type"], as_index=False).agg({"Winner_pokemon_type":"count"})`, but the issue with this approach is that for pandas bug vs. dark is a different combination than dark vs.bug is there any way to solve this in python?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this problem using python lists.

```
df = ...
import itertools
a = [df['First_pokemon_type'].tolist(),df['Second_pokemon_type'].tolist()]
print(list(itertools.product(*a)))
```